# Getting issue while AOSP – CREATING A SYSTEM SERVICE

Tags: android, android-source

I am new in the development of the AOSP environment. I'm trying to create a system service using the following url (sample source code)
[http://devarea.com/aosp-creating-a-system-service](http://devarea.com/aosp-creating-a-system-service/#comments),
I'm receiving a problem when I'm running the application:

**Logcat error message:**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bojojnav.sampleserviceapp/com.example.bojojnav.sampleserviceapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find ISampService by name [com.android.sampservice.ISampService]
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find ISampService by name [com.android.sampservice.ISampService]
                      at com.android.sampservice.SampManager.<init>(SampManager.java:43)
                      at com.android.sampservice.SampManager.getInstance(SampManager.java:18)
                      at com.example.bojojnav.sampleserviceapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
```

please help me to resolve issue.

Comment: Did you add a permissions file as suggested in the article? Also, it looks like you may be trying to create an instance of `ISampService` instead of its implementation, `ISampServiceImpl`. Is the service declared in your application manifest?